# AsyncTask: How do I access onPostExecute parameters?

Tags: android

So I am passing in a String array into my onPostExecute method, but I was wondering how I can access the output of this thread in the next activity... i.e. Page.class

Right now I am using a putExtra, is there anything else I can do? After the putExtra here, how can I access this in Page.class. Note that Page.class is NOT the class that starts this thread.

```
public void onPostExecute(String[] x){
    d.dismiss();
    Intent i= new Intent(ctx,Page.class);
    i.putExtra("values", x);
    ctx.startActivity(i);



Intent b = getIntent();
        String[] values = b.getStringArrayExtra("values");
        Log.d("hello", values[0]);
```

Comment: Everyone's solutions worked. I forgot to remove a line of code because I implemented AsyncTask from a single thread and didn't remove all the lines i needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Page.class` is the activity started by `onPostExecute()`, right?

Then whatever you put in the Extra [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) would be accessible. @Gix already posted the way to access the bundle, so I am not repeating here. But please checkout the bundle class to see what you can put inside (Basically almost all primitives and arrays are OK)

Comment: Just Read your edit. Please make sure your `x` you put inside the intent is not empty. Or easier, you first log following out:
        String[] values = b.getStringArrayExtra("values");
        Log.d("hello", values.length + " ");

Comment: Just wanna make sure you ain't putting zero-length array to it.

Comment: yea xandy is right, make sure your result array **x** is not empty so just do some logging to see what you are sending through and what you are receiving once you start the new activity.

Comment: I am pretty sure the x is not empty. I logged `x[0]` in the `onPostExecute` method and it returned the expected value. but when i try to access it in the page class it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting the activity Page straight from the onPostExecute you should be able to access the extras in the Page Activity without any problem. The way to do that is using the following code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String values = extras.getString("values");
```

and there you have them

Comment: this is not working, i get a null pointer exception, i added what i tried

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate(...)` of your 'Page' Activity, simply use `Intent i = getIntent()` then use `String[] values = i.getStringArrayExtra("values")`

Comment: when I do this, I get a null pointer exception when trying to reverence values[0], i added what i tried